# can i return result to ajax via C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have some code that passes inner html to the code behind C# that is responsible store this into the database. Now i want to return some result back to the ajax function that will help me to render the page on conditional based.
Here is the ajax function and the code behind
you can see in ajax's success method i am rendering to the "list.aspx"

i want this rendering on condition that will be handled inside the C#

i want to render page based upon this condition

**Ajax**

```
$('#Button1').click(function () {


                    var HTML = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
                       var Fname = document.getElementById("MyText").value;
                      Senddata = { "HTML": HTML, "Fname": Fname };
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Post",
                        url: "/wwwroot/Default.aspx/save",
                        data: JSON.stringify(Senddata),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            console.log(result);
                            //    alert("Records Added");
                            window.open("List.aspx", "_self")
                            //    window.location = result;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

**C# code**

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static void save(string HTML, string Fname)
        {

```
    HttpContext.Current.Session["GUID"] = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());

    try
    {
       ............
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        string tempUser = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempUser))
        {
            tempUser = "0";
        }

   ....................

      .
        con.Close();
 if (tempUser == "0")
                        {


                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("login.aspx");

                        }
                        else
                        {


                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("list.aspx");
                        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CommonBLL.WriteExceptionLog(ex, "Form Save Default.aspx");
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I understand is, you want to send data back from Save method to Ajax success callback... am I correct?

Comment: Yeah absolutely correct @Vim

Comment: Is save working correctly?

Comment: it works fine, but when after checking condition if (tempUser == "0")
                    {

// it need to return some result that will help ajax's success method to render login.aspx

                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("login.aspx");

It never render or take me to the login.aspx page

Comment: Got it. Change the return type of Save method to string, instead of void. Example: public static string save(string HTML, string Fname) and then after the con.Close(), return a string value and make sure that you are receiving at success callback. If you need a code sample, let us know.

Comment: can i return the string inside checking the conditon if (tempUser == "0") {

yes your sampple code help me. its also good if u edit my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74454/discussion-between-jot-and-vim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    This is how your c# code should look like. Let's discuss in chat if you have more questions.

    //change the return type to string
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string save(string HTML, string Fname) 
    {            

    ....

    try
    {
        ....

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempUser))
        {
            tempUser = "0";
            return "some value 1";
         }

        ....

        con.Close();  
        return "some value 2";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CommonBLL.WriteExceptionLog(ex, "Form Save Default.aspx");
        throw ex;
    }        
}
```